# cacellation token enabled after a while

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, token, cancellation-token

i have an micro service application who has many projects
i called service who need three other service project to complete task
when i called the method it enable cancellation token and i do not know what is the error
it works perfectly on debug mode but when i published it on server it shows me

> The operation was canceled.

the method is **async** and **task** operation base

1. increase time out on iis did not work
2. `Task.Run()=>(mytask()).(SetMyTimout);` didn't work
3. `await mymethod().wait(timeout);` didn't work

Comment: "await mymethod().wait(timeout);" returns a bool, so you can´t await it. "Task.Run()=>(mytask()).(SetMyTimout);" is not a valid C# syntax. Could you please provide a little more details? Otherwise its hard to understand what you want to achieve and what you have already tried.

Comment: @Darem i know the returns and i just write a example code not for complie i know the code is var t = Task.Run(() => ShowThreadInfo("Task") );  t.Wait(); my problem is The operation was canceled. Message when i execute the method who called 3 micro service by order